# Problem with solving the ODE equation $ty'=3y+t^5y^\frac{1}{3}$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have problem with solving the following equation:

> $$ty'=3y+t^5y^\frac{1}{3}$$

I know it's easy without the $y^\frac{1}{3}$ term, but I'm confused now.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: exclamation points and smileys are fine in chats or text messages, but please stick to *asking a question*, **and also including context**: *what you've tried, including your workings; or where you encountered the question; etc.*

Comment: it is a Bernoulli ode

Comment: you can Google for it there are many solved examples

Answer (score 1):

It's a Bernoulli's ODE, first $y=0 $ is a solution , now by dividing by $y^{1/3} $ we find $ \frac{y'}{y^{1/3}} - 3 \frac{ty}{y^{1/3}} = t^4  $ , Now we put $z= \frac{1}{y^{\frac{-2}{3}}}$ we will find by replacing in the ODE $ \frac{2}{3}z'-\frac{3}{t}z=4t^4 $ by solving it you will find easily $z$ then $y$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=u^3$ then $y'=3u'u^2$ and 
$$3tu'u^2=3u^3+t^5u$$
$$tu'=u+\dfrac{t^5}{3u}$$
$$tu'-u=\dfrac{t^5}{3u}$$
$$\dfrac{tu'-u}{t^2}=\dfrac{t^3}{3u}$$
$$\left(\dfrac{u}{t}\right)'=\dfrac{t^2}{3}\dfrac{t}{u}$$
$$\left(\dfrac{u}{t}\right)\left(\dfrac{u}{t}\right)'=\dfrac{t^2}{3}$$
$$\int2\left(\dfrac{u}{t}\right)d\left(\dfrac{u}{t}\right)=\int\dfrac{2t^2}{3}dt$$
$$\left(\dfrac{u}{t}\right)^2=\dfrac{2t^3}{9}+C$$
$$\color{blue}{y^\frac23=\dfrac{2t^5}{9}+Ct^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

You have a first order nonlinear ODE. You are dealing with one of [these animals](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliDifferentialEquation.html)

**HINT**

Write your ODE in the following form:

$$ \frac{2 y' }{3 y^{1/3}} - \frac{2y ^{2/3}}{t} = \frac{2t^4}{3}. $$

This is achieved by dividing by  $\frac{3}{2} t y^{1/3}$.

To proceed with the solution introduce a new variable $v(t)$ such that

$$ v(t) = y(t)^{2/3}.$$

After simplification you will get an ODE in the following form

$$ v'(t) - \frac{2}{t}v(t) = \frac{2t^4}{3}. $$

Solve accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

for your Control the solution is given by $$\left( y \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2/3}-2/9\,{t}^{5}-{t}^{2}{\it 
\_C1}=0
$$